# autocomplete slow with large database search

Tags: mysql, sql, autocomplete

I've spent a considerable amount of time trying to track this one down.  I've used a boxed autocomplete on my site (http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/).  As you type the word, it sends it as a GET variable to a page for processing where it is searched for in a mySQL database.  The page looks like this:

```
$get = $_GET['query'];
$query = "SELECT title,author,id,isbn10,isbn13 FROM textbook
        WHERE title LIKE '" . $get . "%'
        OR author LIKE '" . $get . "%'
        LIMIT 5
        ";
$result = mysql_query($query,$connection);
$resString = "";
$idString = "";
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$resString .= "'" . title($data['title']) . " by " . $data['author'] . "',";
$idString .= "'" . $data['id'] . "',";
}
$resString = rtrim($resString, ',');
$idString = rtrim($idString, ',');
$code = "{\n";
$code .= "query:'" . $get . "',\n";
$code .= "suggestions:[" . $resString . "],\n";
$code .= "data:[" . $idString . "]\n";
$code .= "}";
echo $code;
```

This outputs a basic JSON dataset that is read and shot back as a result.  The problem is that it has been REALLY slow.  the "LIMIT 5" helped a ton to speed it up some.  However, still running slow after the initial result set shows.  I may type in "hum" and it will come back with a quick result set, but any letters/words after that take 4-6 seconds to show.  The database is 300K records roughly.  Attached is a picture of my database structure page:

[database http://semesterkey.com/images/data.jpg](http://semesterkey.com/images/data.jpg)

Im just trying to figure out how to speed things up.  I think it might be my database structure, it could be how Im querying?  I just have no idea.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Yogesh is right, you should index fields by which you search.

Comment: Would you recommend a clustered or non-clustered index? Newbie here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only solution is that use Indexing on column which you want to show in autocomplete in your Database, hope this will help you

Comment: There might be more solutions, but this one is the first to try :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer to your problem is an index on the (author, title) group of columns. It will grow the amount of space used by the DB and will decrease the performance on INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE in that table, but it will increase the interrogation performance.

Comment: would you recommend a non-clustered index or a clustered?  I apologize, I'm just getting my feet wet in this area of programming!

Comment: you should try a non-clustered first. Only if the performance is not satisfying, you can move to a clustered index. The clustered one is physically reordering the records. That's a hard core job.

Answer (score 0):

make index on author and title may help you to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax help for those who don't grasp which above answer

`ALTER TABLE`Your_table_name`ADD INDEX (`column_title`)` ;